# RequireJS, how to load js file

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to load app.js file in main.js, but I'm getting:

> TypeError: App is undefined

**index.html**

```
<script data-main='js/main' src="require.min.js"></script>
```

**/js/main.js**

```js
require([
    'app'
],function(App){
    console.log(App); // App is undefined
    App.initialize();
});
```

**/js/app.js**

```js
define([
    'router'
], function(Router) {
    var initialize = function() {
        Router.initialize();

        return {
            initialize : initialize
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you require module 'app', the `App` variable will refer to whatever the 'app' module returns. However, in your case it does not return anything:

```js
function(Router) {
    var initialize = function() {
        Router.initialize();

        return {
            initialize : initialize
        }
    }

    // returns nothing, i.e. undefined
}
```

Looks like you should move the `return` block outside the `initialize` function, essentially it could be rewritten as:

```js
function (Router) {
    return {
        initialize: function() {
            Router.initialize();
        }
    }
}
```